# Why does the response time curve of NodeJS API become sinus like under load?

Tags: node.js, api, jmeter, load-testing

I am currently performing an API Load Test on my NodeJS API using JMeter and am completely new to the field. The API is deployed on an IBM Virtual Server with 4 vCPUs and 8GB of RAM.
One of my load tests includes stress testing the API in a 2500 thread (users) configuration with a ramp-up period of 2700ms (45 min) on infinite loop. The goal is not to reach 2500 threads but rather to see at what point my API would throw its first error.
I am only testing one endpoint on my API, which performs a bubble sort to simulate a CPU intensive task. Using Matplotlib I plotted the results of the experiment. I plotted the response time in ms over the active threads. [image]

I am unsure why the response time curve becomes **sinus like** once crossing roughly 1100 Threads. I expected the response time curve keep rising in the same manner it does in the beginning (0 - 1100 threads). Is there an explanation for the **sinus like** behaviour of the curve towards the end?

Thank you!

**Graph:**

Red - Errors

Blue - Response time

Comment: Looks suspiciously like garbage collector kicking in. Check the RAM usage on the node server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 possible reasons for this:

1. Your application cannot handle such a big load and performs frequent [garbage collection](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-node-js-garbage-collection/) in order to free up resources or tasks are queuing up as application cannot process them as they come. You can try using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-node-js-garbage-collection/) to ensure that the system under test doesn't lack CPU or RAM
2. JMeter by default comes up with relatively low [JVM Heap size](https://medium.com/@abigaelse2/jvm-memory-heap-80075e4ffeb7) and a very little [GC tuning](https://sematext.com/blog/java-garbage-collection-tuning/) (like it's described in Concurrent, [High Throughput Performance Testing with JMeter](https://howtojboss.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/concurrent-high-throughput-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article where the guy has very similar symptoms) so it might be the case JMeter cannot send requests fast enough, make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and consider going for [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) if needed.